# Is there a proper term for twacking?

Tags: word-choice

Hitting something with the finger. Usually from being released after build-up tension with the thumb.

Comment: Do you mean 'snapping' your fingers? One can 'thwack' someone but that is not limited to doing it with your fingers. 'twacking' is not an English word, so it's hard to tell what you're intending? What is the term for it in your native language? Have you tried translating online?

Answer (score 1):

Define *“proper”*. :)

I suppose that ***thumping*** something with your finger has less “improper” twang to it, and that ***smiting*** something with your finger sounds more awesome still, but guitarists — seldom folks to get hung up on matters of propriety —  simply call this [***finger thwacking***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFo7_eyd58Q).

Is that what you mean?

I confess that if it were me and I were feeling a wee bit naughty, I might be tempted into minting me a nifty neologism like *fthwacking* for this act, which although perhaps less prim than queenly English would like any good shibboleth serve to separate those who can say *fifths* and *twelfths* from those who cannot. :)

Answer (score 1):

The common expression is 'finger flick' as demonstrated on Youtube.

[Animated Finger Flick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy2DZdBiAmA)